# why calling apply on Math.max works and without it doens't

Tags: javascript

If you asked me to get the max of an array, I would just do:

```
var nums = [66,3,8,213,965,1,453];
Math.max.apply(Math, nums);
```

of course, I could also do:
    nums.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b}.pop(nums.length);

but I have to be honest. I need to know WHY that works - using .apply(Math,nums). If I just did this:

```
Math.max(nums);
```

that would not work.

by using apply, I pass in Math as this - and nums for the array.  But I want to know the intricacies of "why" that the first works and the latter doesn't. What magic is happening?

There is something fundamental I am not wrapping my brains around. I have read a bunch about "call and apply", but many times some cool tricks can be had like the one above, and I feel I am missing something deeper here.

Comment: Read about what `.apply` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can read here about [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), `apply` Calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided as an `array`. So the second parameter for the `apply` function accepts `arrays`, that's why it works.

While [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) itself expects any number of parameters NOT an array of them:

```
Math.max(66,3,8,213,965,1,453) //will work
Math.max([66,3,8,213,965,1,453]) //will not work
```

Usually you will be using `apply` for calling functions with dynamic parameters (e.g. user generated) that you don't know the number of parameters. On the other hand if you have a fixed number of parameters then you can easily provide them to `Math.max()` function.

Comment: Ok, I dig what you are saying and am already familiar with it somewhat, BUT what I missed and what I think you cleared up is that apply allows me to "change" the context of acceptance. yes?

Comment: yes. and also take time to read more about the first parameter of the `apply` that changes `this` in the function being called.